# Implement Copy for a struct with a Vec field

Tags: rust

Hi I have folowing code:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct PriceCheckerState {
   settings: Settings,
   prev_notification: Option<Notification>,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Settings {
    threshold: f32,
    notifications_disabled: bool,
}


#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Notification {
    gain: f32,
    user_ids: Vec<f32>,
}
```

And I want to copy state like:

```
    let updatedState = State {
        settings: updatedSettings
        ..state
    };
```

It fails that struct Notification has not defined copy makro, if I add it, then it complains that Vec has no defined copy. I understand that Vec has only clone defined. Is there any hack how to make a copy of struct with Vec (even if this Vec would be cloned)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Copy` is used only for simple bitwise copies, i.e. the ones which can be implemented as mere `memcpy`. If any component of the type can't be copied this way (and `Vec` certainly can't), the whole struct is forced to be not `Copy`.

What you seem to want is an explicit call to `clone` whenever your state semantically should be copied:

```
let updatedState = State {
    settings: updatedSettings,
    ..state.clone(),
};
```

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. And by the way, does compiler recognise, that there is not necessary to not make a deep clone of "prev_notification" property and it can just mutate variable "state" because I do not use it any more?

Comment: It can be optimized out, but this is not guaranteed. If you want to mutate `state` in place, just mutate it - if you don't use it anymore, this should pose no problem.